# Does being engaged (to be married) carry any legal significance?

Tags: united-states, france, marriage

Being married carries specific legal consequences, e.g. spouses typically are treated differently under tax law, divorce property law, inheritance law, have rights regarding medical visitation and medical decisions. Sometimes insurance carriers treat them differently, though i'm unsure if that's legally mandated or just standard practice.

Absent a specific signed engagement contract which stipulates specific legal ramifications, **does being engaged (to be married) carry any legal significance**?

Jurisdiction is either USA, or France (I'm interested in both).

Significance may be to either party of the engagement, or to third parties (e.g. in how they have to treat engaged partner, or the couple, differently).

Just to be clear, consequences must stem from the fact of engagement, NOT from things like co-habitation, being declared "domestic partners" etc...

Comment: This question was prompted by the discussion on http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/36404/6523, wasn't it?

Comment: @jwodder - yes, that's where I got the idea.

Comment: It entitles you to sue for breach of promise.

Comment: Related question, does "spousal privilege" (the idea that you can't be compelled to testify against your spouse) extend to engaged/unmarried domestic partners?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are only a few areas of law of which I am aware that U.S. law treats people who are engaged to be married differently (although perhaps with more thought I could expand the list).

1. Fiance(e)s come under a [special immigration status](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/IMBRA.html) when applying for a visa.
2. There is a body of law related to whether an engagement ring is an absolute gift or is conditional upon being married (this is not uniform from state to state and I don't recall what the majority rule in those cases is under the common law). [In South Carolina](https://scholar.google.com.au/scholar_case?case=16439775895686510622&hl=en&as_sdt=6&as_vis=1&oi=scholarr&sa=X&ei=yunaU-GFE5fq8AXRp4H4Aw&ved=0CB4QgAMoATAA), ownership disputes over engagement rings are litigated as breach of promise to marry actions.
3. Pre-marital agreements governing a future marriage can be made by people who are engaged (although a post-nuptial agreement is also equal in effect in most cases).
4. People who are engaged, like spouses, are generally considered to be in a "confidential relationship" with each other which imposes higher duties with respect to fairness in their dealings with each other than strangers, but generally less high duties than fiduciaries.
5. While not strictly arising from the status of being engaged, adult cohabitants are generally [agents for service of process of each other at their shared home](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcp/rule_4), and are often considered to have a legally significant relationship for purposes of domestic violence statutes (usually related to either domestic violence crimes or temporary restraining orders).

I am not familiar enough with the law of France to fully answer the balance of the question, which someone more familiar with that law can expand upon.

But, there is similarly a special immigration status in French law for a fiance(e).

And, French law, in a flourish so romantic it could scarcely be any other country's law, also [allows people who are engaged a right to marry after one of them has died in certain circumstances](http://www.thelocal.fr/20140228/grieving-french-woman-to-marry-dead-partner):

"The legislation that allows posthumous marriages stems back to when a dam burst in 1959 and killed 420 people in southern France." It was most recently invoked in 2014 when a grieving French woman was granted permission by the French President to marry her former fiancé, who tragically died in 2012, just a month before they were due to wed. To be eligible the bride to be had "to convince the President of France that her’s was a special case and that her love for Michael went beyond the grave. It took four letters to the president and 20 months of waiting, desperately hoping for a positive response." The President's discretion in this matter is somewhat similar to the pardon power in U.S. law.

This French law was also [invoked in 2009](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2009/nov/17/french-woman-marries-dead-partner). The law in question is [set forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posthumous_marriage) at Articles 171 of the French Civil Code. [In English translation](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/content/download/1950/13681/version/3/file/Code_22.pdf) this states:

> Article 171 The President of the Republic may, for serious reasons,
>   authorize the celebration of the marriage if one of the future spouses
>   is dead providing a sufficient gathering of facts establishes
>   unequivocally his consent. In this case, the effects of the marriage
>   date back to the day preceding that of the death of the spouse.
>   However, this marriage does not carry with it any right of intestate
>   succession to the benefit of the surviving spouse and no matrimonial
>   regime is considered to have existed between the spouses.

I am aware of [one documented case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posthumous_marriage) where a court entered a post-humous marriage in the United States between people who were engaged, but I am not familiar with any legal authority actually authorizing that action.

Comment: Great answer! One nitpick: Are prenups actually affected by being engaged? Can people who aren't engaged enter into prenup and if so, would it be legally any different? If not, #3 seems like it doesn't matter to the answer.

Comment: Also, I would de-emphacise #5, to be honest. You yourself noted that it's contingent on co-habitation, which is not really related to engegement (you can be engaged but not cohabiting, or vice versa). May be split off #3 and #5 into separate section at the end that is "not really about engagement but relevant to the topic"?

Comment: Apropos nothing, reading this answer gave me an idea of an unrelated question (just posted) re: prenups/postnups

Comment: If you are entering into a prenup, you are by definition engaged to be married.

Comment: i'm not sure that's a legal rule (as opposed to rule of thumb)?

Comment: @DVK Consider Colorado Revised Statutes § 14-2-302(5) which is based on a uniform state law widely adopted: '"Premarital agreement' means *an agreement between individuals who intend to marry* which affirms, modifies, or waives a marital right or obligation during the marriage or at legal separation, marital dissolution, death of one of the spouses, or the occurrence or nonoccurrence of any other event. The term includes an amendment, signed before the individuals marry, of a premarital agreement." Thus, people who aren't married and aren't engaged can't enter into a marital agreement.

Comment: OK, i'll post that as a separate questoin, so you can turn that into an answer :)

Comment: In Australia you can be deemed to "have a partner", particularly if you spend time under the same roof repeatedly. This can affect any income support payments you may be claiming.

Comment: @ohwilleke: I don't think all couples who "intend to marry" count as engaged.

Comment: What about the "promise to marry"? An engagement may be required for lawsuit if the promise to marry is broken.

Comment: @Agent_L Good point. There was a common law cause of action for breach of promise to marry. I'm not away of any U.S. jurisdiction where this remains good law. Most were abolished with heart balm statues generally and I'm not aware that the cause of action exists in the handful of jurisdictions that still have heart balm statutes, but I am always willing to learn about obscure exceptions.

Comment: A survey of the law on promise to marry is found at http://www.lawreform.ie/_fileupload/consultation%20papers/wpbreachofpromise.htm but isn't very comprehensive or up to date in the U.S. analysis. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breach_of_promise

Answer (score 5):

**does being engaged (to be married) carry any legal significance**

Depending on your definition of "engaged", yes: you cannot marry without announcing your engagement.

[Banns of marriage -- France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banns_of_marriage#France)

> French civil law requires the publication of banns of marriage in the towns where intended spouses are living. It should be displayed in the town hall ten days before the marriage.

Or, from an official web page, [Mariage en France](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F930):

> Le mariage ne peut pas être célébré avant le 10è jour depuis, et non compris, celui de la publication des bans.

Comment: So, what happens if they aren't posted?

Comment: If you didn't get them posted then you haven't done enough paper-work to get married. You can't just show up at the town hall and say "marry us": the registrant would presumably tell you, "sorry, you have to publish your intention first, and then come back in 10 days".

Comment: Something similar in the UK: you need to [give notice](https://www.gov.uk/marriages-civil-partnerships/what-you-need-to-do), after which they'll give you a license (i.e. give you permission) to marry.

Comment: I'm not claiming that [this person](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/36404/2703) has taken the legal step described in this answer, i.e. that she has had bans published. In fact that hat sounds to me improbable, since that involves an obligatory interview with an official who would ask the pair whether they are marriageable.

Comment: In Hungary, the wait time is 30 days but under some circumstances (pregnancy is a common one) it's possible to get a weaver but the processing time for that is 10-14 days usually...

Comment: Good point. Many or most U.S. jurisdiction have abolished this requirement (which in the U.K. was tie to the established church and had some other consequences for non-Anglicans) or the secular equivalent. But, apparently in France you need to profess an intent to be married well in advance of doing so.